# Unable to bind List<T> to a combo box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using win forms and trying to populate a combo box. Here is my code-

```
comboBoxMaterial.DataSource = _materials;
comboBoxMaterial.DisplayMember = "name_ee_EE";
comboBoxMaterial.ValueMember = "tssaNameId";
```

`_materials` is a List of a certain type that I have created. It looks like this in the debugger-

[image]

The problem is, when my form loads the  combo box is empty but in the debugger I can see `comboBoxMaterial.Items` has the items in that. As per the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` that I have set, the combo box should get populated based on the data source. Also I don't get any errors.

Comment: Looks like you miss the leading underscore in Displaymember assignment? Should be comboBoxMaterial.DisplayMember = "_name_ee_EE"; Still, that does not explain why the combobox looks empty. Also, that _name_ee_EE of T, is it a property (does it have get and set functions)?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code to create and select a new object with `id` and `name` as the properties. Just like this-

```
comboBoxMaterial.DataSource = _materials.Select(m => new { id = m.tssaNameId, name = m.name_en_CA}).ToList();
comboBoxMaterial.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBoxMaterial.ValueMember = "id";
```

So this works now.